# Unit testing with firebase auth emulator requires real service account?

Tags: javascript, firebase

We are using the firebase emulators to write integration tests. One of our functions modifies the claims on a user. As such, our test checks to see if the claim has been added. In our test, we call the following function:

```
         admin.auth().getUser(user.userId)
```

Our intention is to then check the claims. Unfortunately, when this function is called, we get an error.

> (node:96985) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Credential
> implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential"
> property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the
> following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making
> request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code:
> ENOTFOUND".

Keep in mind we are running against the local auth emulator, not a cloud service. We found an issue on github which seems to be related: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1708

Unfortunately, the recommended course of action in that issue is to use an actual service account file from an actual cloud service. We do not check such files into our repos as this would be a security hazard. Does anyone know of a better way to deal with this situation?

In case it is relevant, we also get the following warning:

> {"severity":"WARNING","message":"Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and
> GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing
> firebase-admin will fail"}